# C# Add header and new column to a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, header, addition

I have the following CSV file:

```
StudentId,FirstName,LastName,DateOfBirth,ImageData
200439932,Bruno,Simoes,07/05/1976,<image converted to Base64 output>
```

I need to add a new header named "Image" at the end of the header and repeat the Image converted as base 64 on the new column. I have been able to get the image as base64 to a varialble and read in the two lines of colde bellow:

```
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(Constants.Locations.localImage));

string csvDataDump = File.ReadAllText(Constants.Locations.localInfo);
```

How would I approach this to add the header and data to the csv file?

Comment: Use `File.ReadAllLines()` instead of `ReadAllText()`, append ",columnName" to the first item of the array (i.e., the first line), loop over the remaining array elements and append ",base64String", and then use `File.WriteAllLines()` to write the data back to the disk.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to change it to an array like so:

```
String [] csvDataDump = File.ReadAllLines(Constants.Locations.localInfo);
```

Now trying to figure how to loop and add the new columns.

Comment: There are CSV file readers. They would likely help, bug your use case is so simple, @ahmedabdelhameed's suggest is all you need. Read up on how to loop over an array. You probably want to use `for` rather than `foreach`. After you add the trailing field, add each modified line to a `List<string>` and then write those modified lined out to a new file.

Comment: All I need now is to add a coma separating the 1st and second base 64 image:
```
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(Constants.Locations.localImage));

            List<string> csvDataDump = File.ReadAllLines(Constants.Locations.localInfo).ToList();

            csvDataDump[0] += ",Image";
            csvDataDump[1] += base64String;

            File.WriteAllLines(Constants.Locations.localInfo, csvDataDump);
```

It's working with this code.

Answer (score 0):

The following changes worked. They are in a loop that checks if the files exits, if don't, they first download the files from the FTP site, and then add the new column and Image to Base64 line.

```
List<string> csvDataDump = File.ReadAllLines(Constants.Locations.localInfo).ToList();

csvDataDump[0] += ",Image";
csvDataDump[1] += "," + base64String;

File.WriteAllLines(Constants.Locations.localInfo, csvDataDump);
```